# Дистрибьютер или дистрибьютор?

Tags: орфография

Если написать дистрибьютер, а не дистрибьютор, то это серьезная ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре фиксируется два варианта. Следовательно, вариант "дистрибьютор" ошибкой не считается.
См.: [Большой толковый словарь русского языка](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/bts/)
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Однако Грамота.ру рекомендует другое написание.

> Как правильно дистрибьютОр или дистрибьютЕр? Говорят, что корректными считаются оба варианта написания. Так ли это?
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Правильно: *дистрибьютор*.

Вопрос.

> Какой вариант предпочтительней: дистрибьютер, дистрибьютор, дистрибутер, дистрибутор?
> Произошло слово, вроде, от английского distributor. По произношению больше подходит первый вариант, но встречал все. В словарях тоже неоднозначно.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

```
Предпочтительно использовать вариант дистрибьютор.
```

Вопрос

Здравствуйте! У вас на сайте в словаре зафиксированы слова "дистрибьютЕр" и "дистрибьютОр". Но в справке вы отвечаете, что правильный только последний вариант. В чем же дело?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

```
Фиксация - в разных словарях. При решении вопроса о правильности написания слова следует опираться на рекомендации орфографического словаря.
```

> ***Дело в том, что в том же орфографическом словаре на Грамоте, это слово отсутствует.  А это (насколько мне известно), последнее издание.***

В словаре ''Слитно или раздельно?'' Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998., дается только такое написание: ***мастер-дистрибьютер******

***дистрибью́тор, -а и дистрибу́тор, -а******Русский орфографический словарь***. Российская академия наук. Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова / О.Е. Иванова, В.В. Лопатин (отв. ред.), И.В. Нечаева, Л.К. Чельцова. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — Москва, 2004. — 960 с.

Comment: В английском у этого слова только один вариант окончания (-or), поэтому под сомнение логичнее ставить другой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите дополнительно [дистрибьютор или дистрибутор](http://re-shenie.ru/news/distribiutor_ili_distributor_kak_pravilno) - какой вариант в каких случаях использовать. Еще приведена статистика использования разных вариантов в интернете. Эта информация может дополнить картину. Рассматриваются все варианты: дистрибьютор, дистрибутор, дистрибьютер, дистрибутер.